# SQL / Python - how to return count for each attribute and sub-attribute from another table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, join

I have SELECT that returns table which has:

-5 possible values for **region** (from 1 to 5) and

-3 possible values for **age** (1-3) with 2 possible values (1 or 2) for **gender** for each age group.

So table 1. looks something like this:

```
+----------+-----------+--------------+---------------+---------+
| att_name | att_value | sub_att_name | sub_att_value | percent |
+----------+-----------+--------------+---------------+---------+
| region   |         1 | NULL         |             0 |      34 |
| region   |         2 | NULL         |             0 |      22 |
| region   |         3 | NULL         |             0 |      15 |
| region   |         4 | NULL         |             0 |      37 |
| region   |         5 | NULL         |             0 |      12 |
| age      |         1 | gender       |             1 |      28 |
| age      |         1 | gender       |             2 |       8 |
| age      |         2 | gender       |             1 |      13 |
| age      |         2 | gender       |             2 |      45 |
| age      |         3 | gender       |             1 |      34 |
| age      |         3 | gender       |             2 |      34 |
+----------+-----------+--------------+---------------+---------+
```

Second table holds records with values from table 1. where table 1. unique values for `att_name` and `sub_att_name` are table 2. attributes:

```
+--------+-----+-----+
| region | age | gen |
+--------+-----+-----+
|      2 |   2 |   1 |
|      3 |   1 |   2 |
|      3 |   3 |   2 |
|      1 |   3 |   1 |
|      4 |   2 |   2 |
|      5 |   2 |   1 |
+--------+-----+-----+
```

I want to return count of each unique values for **region** and **age**/**gender** attributes from second table.

Final result should look like this:

```
+----------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+---------+
| att_name | att_value | att_value_count | sub_att_name | sub_att_value | sub_att_value_count | percent |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+---------+
| region   |         1 | 1               | NULL         |             0 | NULL                |      34 |
| region   |         2 | 1               | NULL         |             0 | NULL                |      22 |
| region   |         3 | 2               | NULL         |             0 | NULL                |      15 |
| region   |         4 | 1               | NULL         |             0 | NULL                |      37 |
| region   |         5 | 1               | NULL         |             0 | NULL                |      12 |
| age      |         1 | NULL            | gender       |             1 | 0                   |      28 |
| age      |         1 | NULL            | gender       |             2 | 1                   |       8 |
| age      |         2 | NULL            | gender       |             1 | 2                   |      13 |
| age      |         2 | NULL            | gender       |             2 | 1                   |      45 |
| age      |         3 | NULL            | gender       |             1 | 1                   |      34 |
| age      |         3 | NULL            | gender       |             2 | 1                   |      34 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+---------+
```

**Explanation**

**Region** - doesn't have sub attribute so `sub_att_name` and `sub_att_value_count` are NULL.
`att_value_count` - counts appearance of each unique region (1 for all regions except for region 3 which shows 2 times).

**Age**/**sex** - counts combinations of appearance of age and sex (groups are 1/1, 1/2, 2/1, 2/2 and 3/1, 3/2).
Since we need to fill in values only for combinations `att_value_count` is NULL.

I'm tagging python and pandas in this question since I don't know if this is possible in SQL at all...i hope it is since we are using analytical tools to pull tables and views from database more naturally.

**EDIT**

SQL - answers looks complicated, I'll test and see if it works tomorrow.

Python - seems more appealing now - is there a way to  parse `att_name` and `sub_att_name`, find 1 level and 2 level attributes and act accordingly? I think this is only possible with python and we do have different attributes and attributes levels. 
I'l already thankful for given answers!

Comment: I would solve it with python using groupby and cumcount. If you accept a python answer, let me know and I'll make it.

Comment: @CeliusStingher if no usable SQL answers appear within 20 minutes I'll tag you in another comment and ask for your answer.

Comment: I am a bit lost however, on how does this new column is created.why for age=1 and gender=1, count is 0, and for age=2 and gender=1, count is 1 for example?  (In table two, I see 2 repetitions of age=2 and gender=1) shouldn't be it be 2?

Comment: @CeliusStingher age=1/gender=1 does not appear in table 2. And for age=2 and gender=2 you are right I've corrected question.

Comment: @CeliusStingher since you put some effort in already I'll mark your answer as correct when I check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is good enough to solve the issue:

```
data_1 = {'att_name':['region','region','region','region','region','age','age','age','age','age','age'],'att_value':[1,2,3,4,5,1,1,2,2,3,3],'sub_att_name':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'gender','gender','gender','gender','gender','gender'],'sub_att_value':[0,0,0,0,0,1,2,1,2,1,2],'percent':[34,22,15,37,12,28,8,13,45,34,34]}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1)

data_2 = {'region':[2,3,3,1,4,5],'age':[2,1,3,3,2,2],'gen':[1,2,2,1,2,1]}
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2)
df_2_grouped = df_2.groupby(['age','gen'],as_index=False).agg({'region':'count'}).rename(columns={'region':'counts'})
df_final = df_1.merge(df_2_grouped,how='left',left_on=['att_value','sub_att_value'],right_on=['age','gen']).drop(columns=['age','gen']).rename(columns={'counts':'sub_att_value_counts'}
```

Output of df_final:

```
   att_name  att_value sub_att_name  sub_att_value  percent  sub_at_value_count
0    region          1          NaN              0       34                 NaN
1    region          2          NaN              0       22                 NaN
2    region          3          NaN              0       15                 NaN
3    region          4          NaN              0       37                 NaN
4    region          5          NaN              0       12                 NaN
5       age          1       gender              1       28                 NaN
6       age          1       gender              2        8                 1.0
7       age          2       gender              1       13                 2.0
8       age          2       gender              2       45                 1.0
9       age          3       gender              1       34                 1.0
10      age          3       gender              2       34                 1.0
```

Comment: this seems like a neat and simple solution! See my edit and please let me know if you can add parsing for one level and 2 level attributes

Comment: Sure, give me 20!

Comment: Ahh, I'm not too sure I undeerstand the question, however I'm way too much of a SQL noob!

Answer (score 1):

This is a pandas solution, basically, `lookup` or `map`.

```
df['att_value_count'] = np.nan
s = df['att_name'].eq('region')

df.loc[s, 'att_value_count'] = df.loc[s,'att_value'].map(df2['region'].value_counts())

# step 2
counts = df2.groupby('age')['gen'].value_counts().unstack('gen', fill_value=0)

df['sub_att_value_count'] = np.nan
tmp = df.loc[~s, ['att_value','sub_att_value']]
counts = df2.groupby('age')['gen'].value_counts().unstack('gen', fill_value=0)

df.loc[~s, 'sub_att_value_count'] = counts.lookup(tmp['att_value'], tmp['sub_att_value'])
```

You can also use `merge` so as it is more SQL friendly. For example, in step 2:

```
counts = df2.groupby('age')['gen'].value_counts().reset_index(name='sub_att_value_count')

(df.merge(counts, 
         left_on=['att_value','sub_att_value'],
         right_on=['age','gen'],
         how = 'outer'
        ) 
   .drop(['age','gen'], axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
    att_name      att_value  sub_att_name      sub_att_value    percent    att_value_count    sub_att_value_count
--  ----------  -----------  --------------  ---------------  ---------  -----------------  ---------------------
 0  region                1  nan                           0         34                  1                    nan
 1  region                2  nan                           0         22                  1                    nan
 2  region                3  nan                           0         15                  2                    nan
 3  region                4  nan                           0         37                  1                    nan
 4  region                5  nan                           0         12                  1                    nan
 5  age                   1  gender                        1         28                nan                      0
 6  age                   1  gender                        2          8                nan                      1
 7  age                   2  gender                        1         13                nan                      2
 8  age                   2  gender                        2         45                nan                      1
 9  age                   3  gender                        1         34                nan                      1
10  age                   3  gender                        2         34                nan                      1
```

---

**Update**: Excuse my SQL skill if this doesn't run (it should though)

```
select 
  b.*
  c.sub_att_value_count
from 
(select 
  df1.*
  a.att_value_count
from
  (select 
    region, count(*) as att_value_count
   from df2
   group by region
  ) as a
  full outer join df1
  where df1.att_value = a.region
) as b
full outer join 
(
    select 
      age, gender, count(*) as sub_att_value_count
    from df2
    group by age, gender
) as c
where b.att_value = c.age and b.sub_att_value = c.gender
```

Comment: Idea would be to extract unique values for att_name  and sub_att_name. So this would be good but hardcoded answer.

Comment: @Harvey I translated the pandas solution to SQL. Please note that I didn't test the code as I don't have a local SQL server :-).

Comment: thank you! Please check my edit in answer and see if you can upgrade your python answer.